# How can I get local minimum point?

Tags: minimum

I'm trying to get a minimum point of the below graph.[image: the amdf graph]

I can get the candidates of local minima, that is 28, 63, 97, 130, and so on. However, I don't know how to filter out real local minimum from the candidates. Is there any algorithm to get local minima?

Comment: Are those x values, or y values?

Comment: yes :) horizontal axis is x-axis, and vertical is y.

Comment: That's not what I meant. 28, 63, 97, 130 are *numbers*, but what are the *coordinates*. They don't seem to align with the graph in any way...

Comment: @jpaugh: they are the x coordinate of several local minima.

Comment: If you have the coordinates of your candidates, simply filter out the ones which aren't in the appropriate range. Then, choose the smallest one.

Comment: The minimum is a point where differential of a function changes sign. 
You have minimums at 31 and, say, 131. How they are different for your requirements? What is the criteria?

Comment: my criteria is 'the minimum point that has lowest value in some range'. I can't determine a range specifically, but I just need the first minimum point which has lowest value.

Comment: If you cannot determine range specifically then your task has no solution. E.g. if length of the range is 511 then minimum will be at 486. But that's not what you want, right?